# Trouble installing R packages with devtools on Travis

Tags: r, travis-ci, devtools

Travis CI builds for the [`drake` R package manual](https://github.com/ropenscilabs/drake-manual) [recently started failing](https://travis-ci.org/ropenscilabs/drake-manual/builds/507491258#L1454-L1459):

```
Downloading GitHub repo ropensci/drake@master
Error: Could not find tools necessary to compile a package
In addition: Warning message:
In get0(oNam, envir = ns) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
Execution halted
The command "Rscript -e 'deps <- devtools::dev_package_deps(dependencies = NA);devtools::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE);if (!all(deps$package %in% installed.packages())) { message("missing: ", paste(setdiff(deps$package, installed.packages()), collapse=", ")); q(status = 1, save = "no")}'" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

I [tried using the development versions of `devtools` and `pkgload`](https://github.com/ropenscilabs/drake-manual/blob/c9b8d3faa8ebbf945abf955b94e3122f06993c6c/.travis.yml#L7-L9), and the [errors changed](https://travis-ci.org/ropenscilabs/drake-manual/builds/507493044#L1153-L1158):

```
$ Rscript -e 'deps <- devtools::dev_package_deps(dependencies = NA);devtools::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE);if (!all(deps$package %in% installed.packages())) { message("missing: ", paste(setdiff(deps$package, installed.packages()), collapse=", ")); q(status = 1, save = "no")}'
Error in match.arg(upgrade, c("ask", "always", "never")) : 
  'arg' must be of length 1
Calls: <Anonymous> ... upgradable_packages -> resolve_upgrade -> match.arg
Execution halted
The command "Rscript -e 'deps <- devtools::dev_package_deps(dependencies = NA);devtools::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE);if (!all(deps$package %in% installed.packages())) { message("missing: ", paste(setdiff(deps$package, installed.packages()), collapse=", ")); q(status = 1, save = "no")}'" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

And when I [also used the development version of `remotes`](https://travis-ci.org/ropenscilabs/drake-manual/builds/507503833#L1153-L1167):

```
$ Rscript -e 'deps <- devtools::dev_package_deps(dependencies = NA);devtools::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE);if (!all(deps$package %in% installed.packages())) { message("missing: ", paste(setdiff(deps$package, installed.packages()), collapse=", ")); q(status = 1, save = "no")}'
drake     (ae093a068... -> 7f40fc6be...) [GitHub]
lazyeval  (0.2.1        -> 0.2.2       ) [CRAN]
polyclip  (1.9-1        -> 1.10-0      ) [CRAN]
purrr     (0.3.1        -> 0.3.2       ) [CRAN]
readxl    (1.3.0        -> 1.3.1       ) [CRAN]
rmarkdown (1.11         -> 1.12        ) [CRAN]
stringi   (1.3.1        -> 1.4.3       ) [CRAN]
tibble    (2.0.1        -> 2.1.1       ) [CRAN]
tinytex   (0.10         -> 0.11        ) [CRAN]
Installing 8 packages: lazyeval, polyclip, purrr, readxl, rmarkdown, stringi, tibble, tinytex
Error in if (type == "binary") { : argument is of length zero
Calls: <Anonymous> ... with_rprofile_user -> with_envvar -> force -> force -> i.p
Execution halted
The command "Rscript -e 'deps <- devtools::dev_package_deps(dependencies = NA);devtools::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE);if (!all(deps$package %in% installed.packages())) { message("missing: ", paste(setdiff(deps$package, installed.packages()), collapse=", ")); q(status = 1, save = "no")}'" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

I believe the builds should succeed, at least up to the point where the actual manual starts to run.

Comment: Update: I cleared the cache and the original build succeeded. Not sure if the R packages needed to by re-synced or it was some other issue that resolved on its own in time. The build with development `devtools` is still failing.

Comment: Same here: https://travis-ci.org/nachti/rwebhdfs/builds/517732797

Comment: See https://travis-ci.com/Exp-Micro-Ecol-Hub/emeScheme/builds/107620556 - same problem with different R version, but works on macOS

Comment: Did not fix it - see https://travis-ci.com/Exp-Micro-Ecol-Hub/emeScheme

Comment: Tried https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2020, but not successfully :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remotes 2.0.3` (now on CRAN) fix this. Travis CI gets it from there.

See
https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2020

Thanks to Jim Hester!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this in devtools 2.0.2 by passing the `upgrade` argument myself: `devtools::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE, upgrade="always")`