# devtools::check() completes with no errors, warnings or messages, travis build fails (devtools::dev_package_deps)

Tags: r, travis-ci, devtools

Devtools installs successfully.  Then it does something weird.

I ran devtools::check() again as a sanity check.  Then I tried clearing the build cache ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208794/trouble-installing-r-packages-with-devtools-on-travis)) from a successful build yesterday, still no dice:

```
* installing *source* package â€˜devtoolsâ€™ ...
** package â€˜devtoolsâ€™ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (devtools)

The downloaded source packages are in
    â€˜/tmp/Rtmpu0ndSC/downloaded_packagesâ€™
travis_time:end:00848b22:start=1554833393126312655,finish=1554833397672697388,duration=4546384733
[0Ktravis_time:start:2105dba8
[0K$ Rscript -e 'deps <- devtools::dev_package_deps(dependencies = NA);devtools::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE);if (!all(deps$package %in% installed.packages())) { message("missing: ", paste(setdiff(deps$package, installed.packages()), collapse=", ")); q(status = 1, save = "no")}'
Error in match.arg(upgrade, c("ask", "always", "never")) : 
  'arg' must be of length 1
Calls: <Anonymous> ... upgradable_packages -> resolve_upgrade -> match.arg
Execution halted
travis_time:end:2105dba8:start=1554833397677461654,finish=1554833401616975939,duration=3939514285
[0K[31;1mThe command "Rscript -e 'deps <- devtools::dev_package_deps(dependencies = NA);devtools::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE);if (!all(deps$package %in% installed.packages())) { message("missing: ", paste(setdiff(deps$package, installed.packages()), collapse=", ")); q(status = 1, save = "no")}'" failed and exited with 1 during .[0m

Your build has been stopped.
```

This is what would normally happen after devtools installs (ie travis installs the rest of the dependencies and starts building):

```
Installing R packages: devtools
4.87s$ Rscript -e 'install.packages(c("devtools"));if (!all(c("devtools") %in% installed.packages())) { q(status = 1, save = "no")}'
Installing package into ‘/home/travis/R/Library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/devtools_2.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 388953 bytes (379 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 379 KB
* installing *source* package ‘devtools’ ...
** package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (devtools)
The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/Rtmp1NRksc/downloaded_packages’
22.02s$ Rscript -e 'deps <- devtools::dev_package_deps(dependencies = NA);devtools::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE);if (!all(deps$package %in% installed.packages())) { message("missing: ", paste(setdiff(deps$package, installed.packages()), collapse=", ")); q(status = 1, save = "no")}'
ggplot2 (3.1.0 -> 3.1.1) [CRAN]
rlang   (0.3.3 -> 0.3.4) [CRAN]
Installing 2 packages: ggplot2, rlang
Installing packages into ‘/home/travis/R/Library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2862022 bytes (2.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.7 MB
trying URL 'http://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/rlang_0.3.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 858992 bytes (838 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 838 KB
* installing *source* package ‘rlang’ ...
** package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/home/travis/R-bin/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./lib/  -I/home/travis/R-bin/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c capture.c -o capture.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/home/travis/R-bin/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./lib/  -I/home/travis/R-bin/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c export.c -o export.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/home/travis/R-bin/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./lib/  -I/home/travis/R-bin/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c internal.c -o internal.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/home/travis/R-bin/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./lib/  -I/home/travis/R-bin/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c lib.c -o lib.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/home/travis/R-bin/lib/R/lib -L/home/travis/R-bin/lib -o rlang.so capture.o export.o internal.o lib.o -L/home/travis/R-bin/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/travis/R/Library/rlang/libs
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (rlang)
* installing *source* package ‘ggplot2’ ...
** package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (ggplot2)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208794/trouble-installing-r-packages-with-devtools-on-travis

Comment: Yes this is a related issue.  However, the OP's strategy of clearing the build cache did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution, but somehow the status of this previously-run build has magically changed to "passing".  I'm not sure how this is even possible... So if you see this error, I guess you just have to wait it out?